# Talend Big Data tMongoDBOutput not working properly

Tags: mongodb, talend, bigdata

I'm having Talend Open Studio for Big Data(ver6.4.0) & I tried for pulling data from Jenkins using `tRESTClient` and inserting into `tMongoDBOutput`. If i select drop down option `tMongoDBOutput --> Basic settings --> Action on data -->insert` & executed the job. It is working fine. But when i use `upsert or update or Upsert with set or Delete`, it is throwing error `Data node or Query node configuration error!`.

I've information like this,

```
tMongoDBOutput --> Advanced settings --> Remove root node(Selected) -->Data node "rootTag" and Query node "".
```

[image]

How to use all Action on data options in tMongoDBOutput without error?

Comment: Seems like wrong configuration, see for example: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=39624

Comment: i attached my screenshot above, i've only rootTag. so that i gave value and there is no Query node.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `data` and `query` node as in the picture on the web page.